# Failed to build the worklight project in xcode

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to Worklight and trying out various examples hosted on IBM worklight website for better understanding.

I have installed Eclipse Juno and IBM Worklight Studio kit on Mac OS X 10.6.8
I already had xcode 4.2 installed on Mac OS X 10.6.8
I had downloaded HelloWorklight example from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#basics and following http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/02_02_Previewing_your_application_on_iOS.pdf for guidlines.

The example is successfully build in Eclipse and deployed to Worklight Server, it can be previewed on Worklight Console as well. Now I tried to Run as Xcode from Eclipse, example was successfully exported to Xcode but when I say Run in xcode, build fails. I see 2 issues under CordovaLib in Xcode, CDVLocation.m with Alert(Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'UIDeviceOrientation' to different enumeration type 'UIInterfaceOrientation')  and CDVAccelerometer.m with Error(Receiver type 'CDVAccelerometer' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'returnAccelInfo').

Please help me with above issues. If I am correct then it seems that library packaged by Worklight fails to compile in xcode.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure about this specific issue, as I never saw it (what is the specific example project that fails for you?), but do note that OS X 10.6 is not supported by Worklight. Only 10.7 and 10.8

Answer (score 0):

Worklight supports OS X 10.7 and above, and Xcode 4.5 and above; At the very least make sure your Xcode version is up to date and try again with Worklight 5.0.6 and [fresh sample applications](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html) that match this Worklight version.